# Looking for MySQL client with method autocomplete and other features

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, autocomplete, console

I am looking for a cool MySQL console (Linux, Ubuntu)?

I want to use shortcuts, method autocompletion, built-in paginator and other cool stuff.

*I know that the standard MySQL console client offers table and database autocompletion, but that is not enough*

Comment: Not a question about programming. Recommendations for good MySQL clients IMHO belong on [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: How did you get 19k reputation on this site and still post this kind of questions here?

Comment: @Konerak, you're right about superuser actually :) but what's wrong with reputation and this kind of questions :)

Comment: Well, since you have 19k reputation, I'd think you'd been around here long enough to have read the F.A.Q. and know which questions belong here, and which not. Actually, I only have 12k rep and have closed tons of questions like this, so you with 19k have problably closed even more off-topic questions and moved them to other sites. I couldn't wrap my head around why you would ask for 'cool client recommendations' on StackOverflow...

Comment: My mistake, true (my lazyness). be happy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about shortcuts or auto completion beyond shell tab completion but from the mysql prompt you can change you're prompt like

```
mysql> pager less
```

Any command after will be fed through less.  You could also use more or grep WHAT_YOU_WANT

Simply type nopager to return to the default.

**Edit**

Along the vein of shortcuts, you might look into creating stored procedures to execute common tasks.